# CSS media query and portrait mode

Tags: css, ipad, mobile, menu

I'm trying to develope a mobile theme based on a Wordpress site.

The question is not about Wordpress but, why my CSS code appear in a way on, e.g. my GNexus (i tried also with a Windows Phone), but quite different on an iPad, always in portrait mode.

In particular i'm trying to create an horizontal nav menu that contains these menu voices:

- MENU (a collapsed voice that contains all pages)
- SEARCH FORM (a search form displayed at the center of the nav bar)
- A LANGUAGE SELECTOR (aligned to the right side of the nav bar, with its own arrow to show other languages available)

I've copied my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/S26zx/

I'm using, also, this media query:

```
@media only screen and (orientation : portrait) {
/* MY CSS CODE */
}
```

These are differences between two version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpJ3E.png

So, why iPad displays sub voices like "Menu" is already clicked, and why that sub-voices are shown in horizontal?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Dude, why php in your stylesheet, seems a bit illogical?

Comment: I'm using a function.php file that override some rules, but that CSS is what i will see in page, so i put it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Set your CSS for different layouts.

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* For general iPad layouts */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! But why "Menu" on iPad is already opened and selected? And why it doesn't display as the GNexus, which CSS style rules are wrong for iPad? I mean, in iPad sub-menu voices are horizontal, but they should be vertical! What's wrong in my CSS?

Comment: Please don't use the combination of bold/quote as a highlight.